# What formulas to use for clicker/incremental games?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formula, game-development, incremental

I'm making a clicker/incremental game in unity for android. Now I'm creating a game economy (prices for improvements, etc.), and I ran into a problem in calculating prices. I found on the Internet such a formula for calculating the price for the next improvement which I use **costnext​=costbase​×(rategrowth​)×owned** *(where costbase​ is the initial cost of the item.
rategrowth​ is the growth rate of the item.
owned is the number of years that have passed)*. But I also need a formula for increasing clicks, like in cookie clicker, please share good formulas, maybe from popular games. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can choose a linear, exponential or polynomial formula.

For linear formulas:

```
choose a slope > 1 (e.g. m=3),
add a base value if you want (e.g. b = 5)
level 1 = 1 * 3 + 5
level 2 = 2 * 3 + 5
level n = n * m + b
```

For exponential formulas:

```
choose a exponential rate (i suggesst between 1 and 2) (e.g. p = 1.5),
choose a coefficient for late balancing (e.g. c = 0.5),
choose a base addition for early balancing (e.g. b = 15)
level n = c * n^p + b
```

For polynomial formulas:

```
You have to make sure your polynomial is always > 0 between (0, ∞)
Its balancing is similar to exponential formulas:
eg formula:
0.01x^3 + 0.1x^2 + 1x + 1
```